# check type in regardingobjectid field in crm 2013 c#

Tags: c#, crm

How can i know which type is in regardingobjectid field in crm c#?

(In our task entity it can be contact, account or incident).
Thank you foe your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Davlumbaz's code is correct but it's for early bound style.
In case of late bound, the code will be:

```
EntityReference regardingRef = (EntityReference)record["regardingobjectid"];
bool isContact = regardingRef.LogicalName == "contact";
```

Answer (score 1):

If that field is of type EntityReference, you can simply use the LogicalName property.

```
record.RegardingObjectId.LogicalName
```

And do a string comparison, or maybe a switch/case statement, depending on your requirements.

```
bool isContact = record.RegardingObjectId.LogicalName == Contact.EntityLogicalName;
```